# Primefaces layout navigation using MenuModel backed menu

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Using PrimeFaces, I want to update/refresh a pages central layout unit based on user interaction with a menu (programmatically created MenuModel) that's included in the same pages east layout unit. From what I can tell, this is not possible, but very well could be wrong. Thanks!

```
subMenu = new Submenu();
subMenu.setLabel("Sales");  
subMenu.setIcon("ui-icon ui-icon-home");
```

-

```
private String currentPage; //holds identifier of current content panel
```

-

```
<!-- navigation panel -->
<p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="false" size="216">
    <ui:include src="./includes/navigationMenu.xhtml" />
</p:layoutUnit>  

<!-- content panel -->
<p:layoutUnit position="center">
    <ui:include src="/views/#{navigationBean.currentPage}.xhtml" />         
</p:layoutUnit>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a listener..

```
MenuItem thisItem = (MenuItem)event.getComponent();
String navigateTo = thisItem.getId();
BeanManager beanManager = new BeanManager();
NavigationBean navBean = (NavigationBean)beanManager.get("navigationBean");
navBean.setCurrentPage(navigateTo);
```

added it to the MenuItem as well as a call to the the templates refresh()...

```
item.addActionListener(new MenuItemListener());
item.setOnsuccess("refresh()");
```

added the refresh method...

```
function refresh(){
    document.location="#{request.contextPath}/faces/views/main.xhtml";
}
```

I really don't care for this solution, but it's better than the alternative, having untestable menu creation logic in markup.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a question: Why do you create a menu programmatically?

Other than that almost everything it's possible: try to include the `ui:include` into a form component with an id (let's say **myFormId**) and try to update this form every time a submenu item is selected; Ok so let's do that programmatically:

```
MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
item.setValue("Dynamic Menuitem");
item.setUrl("#");                    //add whatever attribute you want to menuItem
item.setUpdate("myFormId");
subMenu.getChildren().add(item);     //then add the menuItem object to subMenu as a child.
```

You can find here the [menuItem API](http://www.dzeek.net/javadoc/primefacesdocs/org/primefaces/component/menuitem/MenuItem.html)

Comment: Because the menu changes depending on who is logged in, and sticking to strict mvc, I don't think the logic behind menu creation should be found in HTML.

I understand what you're doing in your code sample, that's is where I'm at. The problem is, how can I update my navigation beans `currentPage` so when I do update that form, the `<ui:include src="/views/#{navigationBean.currentPage}.xhtml" />` directs to the proper page.

This is what I'm thinking is not doable. 

Thanks!!

Comment: @Half_Duplex Why my solution doesn't work? You have to think and search a little: you create some menuItems, insert them into a submenu, and beside update you can use the method `item.addActionListener`, implement some code that would change `currentPage` variable dynamically, at each menuItem select... see here some relevant example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432897/executing-the-actionlistener-of-a-primefaces-menu-item-leads-to-an-illegalstat

Comment: I've tried using the action listener, it doesn't work properly. I agree, you're solution SHOULD work, logically and according to the API, but for some reason it doesn't. When I implemented the API, it did update the bean, but it seemed the page was updated prior to the bean being updated, so I didn't see the "new" content until I refreshed the browser. Also, I tried using onSuccess(). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Half_Duplex Revise your code and also try using a RequestContext object...update and change value using RequestContext

Comment: To me, it just seems a shortcoming in the API to not be able to pass EL the same way as JS is passed. I'm semi-new to JSF, I'm sure there's a way to get this to work, but ActionListeners and pulling from the RequestContext seems a lot of code to maintain for a simple navigational menu. Thanks for your help spauny!

Comment: @Half_Duplex Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, I went ahead with implementing the listener class and I also made use of the MenuItems onSuccess.