# Can't get MenuItem to have its ActionListeners called

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, actionlistener

I am trying to get a Primefaces `MenuItem` [within a `Menubar`] to emit an `ActionEvent` and call a method when pressed, however, the listening methods are never called, and I have no idea why:

xhtml page:

```
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <p:menubar model="#{testBean.model}" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" />
    <h:outputText value="#{testBean.confirmation}" />
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

jsf bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class TestBean implements ActionListener{

    MenuModel model = new DefaultMenuModel();
    private String confirmation = "negative";

    public TestBean() {
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
        item.setValue("Click");
        item.setUrl("#");
        item.addActionListener(this);
        model.addMenuItem(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void processAction(ActionEvent event)
            throws AbortProcessingException {

        // EXECUTION NEVER REACHES HERE!
        confirmation = "positive";
    }

    public MenuModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public String getConfirmation() {
        return confirmation;
    }
}
```

It might help to visualise the very simple output:

[image]

I'm using Primefaces 3.1.0, and JSF 2.0

Comment: This question deals with very similar code, yet seems to have more success: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432897/executing-the-actionlistener-of-a-primefaces-menu-item-leads-to-an-illegalstat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem with the original code was that I needed a unique Id. I discovered this early on, but it lead to another very annoying issues: the action listener would be called, but the page would not update. To solve this issue (as described [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7103)), you either disable ajax on the MenuItem or customise how it updates.

The correct constructor code is:

```
public TestBean() {
    MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
    item.setValue("Click");

    // New code:
    item.setId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().createUniqueId());
    item.setAjax(false);

    item.setUrl("#");
    item.addActionListener(this);
    model.addMenuItem(item);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My first suggestion is to add some kind of debug logging to your action listener in order to find out, whether it got called or not. If it gets called but your site isn't rendering the changes it might be due to the following reasons.

- The action listener does not trigger an update of the client side DOM.
- The submit button triggers a request. The managed bean gets pulled up and reinitialized with default values, since it gets managed in a request scope. You should try putting your bean into `@ViewScoped` or `@SessionScoped` management.

By the way, we do not implement `ActionListener`. We assign method expressions to the menu items. Here is a short mockup example: We used an action of a menu item to toggle button states of a context menu. Hope I could help you  somehow.

Facelet snippet:

```
<p:menu model="#{menuBean.model}" />
```

Bean snippet:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MenuBean implements Serializable {

    private MenuModel model;
    private boolean cutAllowed = false;

    /** Creates a new instance of MenuBean */
    public MenuBean() {
        model = new DefaultMenuModel();

        //First submenu
        Submenu submenu = new Submenu();
        submenu.setLabel("Dynamic Submenu 1");

        MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
        item.setValue("toggle");
        item.setUpdate("contextMenu");
        item.setAjax(true);
        item.setIcon("ui-icon ui-icon-disk");
        ExpressionFactory factory = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
        MethodExpression methodExpression = factory.createMethodExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), "#{menuBean.toggleCutState}", String.class, new Class[]{});

        item.setActionExpression(methodExpression);

        submenu.getChildren().add(item);

        model.addSubmenu(submenu);
    }

    public boolean isCutAllowed() {
        return cutAllowed;
    }

    public void setCutAllowed(boolean cutAllowed) {
        this.cutAllowed = cutAllowed;
    }

    public String toggleCutState() {
        toggleCutState(null);
        return null;
    }

    public void toggleCutState(ActionEvent event) {
        this.cutAllowed = !this.cutAllowed;
        System.out.println("toggle called");
    }       

    public MenuModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }  
}
```

Comment: When you say we don't implement ActionListener, is that meaning implementing ActionListener wont work? It looks simpler than the way you have proposed.

Comment: I have tried with @SessionScoped, and have debugged to confirm that the code is not being reached. :(

Comment: @Mowgli To be honest, I haven't even tried implementing ActionListener, and I don't know if it would work. We have more than one action in our menu bar, so we would need to implement an action listener for each menu item, which seems overkill to me. Have you tried using a method expression, yet?

Comment: @Mowgli - You might have a look at this forum post: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7103 - It discusses how to use a method expression in order to add an action listener to the menu items. Good luck .-)

Comment: Yes I have tried using method expression, and was faced with similar issues, they also force you to make the class a managed bean.

Comment: That forum post was exceedingly helpful! There are a number of things that it explained and addressed. I'll write the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

@Mogwli, item.setId((new UiViewRoot()).createUniqueId()); will cause an IllegalArgumentException since new UIViewRoot() will not be context aware... Should have been item.setId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().createUniqueId());

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion seems like a good idea. I shall update the answer. However, I wasn't getting `IllegalArgumentExceptions`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code snippet shows an `<h:commandButton>` which is **not** the Primefaces commandButton `<p:commandButton>`.

Secondly, you are not specifying the `actionListener` attribute of the commandButton to point to `processAction`.

```
<p:commandButton value="submit" actionListener="#{testBean.processAction}" />
```

Comment: But the listening method is listening to the menubar item button/link (not the commandButton). If MenuItems didn't emit events, then they wouldn't have an addListener method, and thus, its valid (I think) to only have an action listener on the MenuItem. I was using <h:commondButton> due to a previous issue, but I'll change it to avoid confusion.